# Questions concerning PCI-E 2.1 vs. 2.0

Tags: pci, pci-express, agp

My older PC's video card just kicked the bucket and has been BSODing. It has a PCI-E x16 slot. Newegg has video cards that are PCI-E x16, 2.0, 2.1, etc.

The slot on my ASUS P5N-E SLI motherboard is 16x. Can I use 16x 2.0 and 2.1 video cards in it? I'm not too familiar with how that works and couldn't find a solid resource on it through Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a 2.1 card in a 2.0 slot or 1.0 slot it will work fine, I have a 2.1 card running in my desktop which has 2.0 right now. However if it is a 2.0 card in a 1.0 slot it will not be as fast, which is to be expected of course.